$f:M\to N$ is bijective and differentiable, then $\text{dim }M=\text{dim } N$
I am looking for proofs (preferably short, basic and simple) for the following statement:

Suppose $M, N$ are smooth manifolds. If there exists an $f:M\to N$ is bijective and $C^1$, then $\text{dim } M=\text{dim } N$.


(Failed) Proof 1: Global rank theorem
Let $X= \{ p\in M: df_p\text{ does not have full rank} \}$
Then, clearly $X$ is closed, because the rank of a sequence of matrices does not increase upon taking limit. Then $\{p\in M: df_p\text{ has full rank}\} = X^c$ is open in $M$.
Proof that $X^c$ is non-empty (open and dense indeed):
Let $R=\min(\text{dim }M,\text{dim }N)$. For each $i\le R$, let $X_i=\{p\in M:\text{rank}(df_p)=i\}$. Let $I=\max\{i : X_i\ne \emptyset\}$.
Then, $X_I=\left(\bigcup^{I-1}_{i=0}X_i\right)^c=\{p\in M: \text{rank}(df_p)\le I-1\}^c$, so $X_I$ is open. There exists a ball $B\subset X_I$ on which $df$ has constant rank $I$. Since $f\vert_B : B\to N$ is injective, by Global Rank Theorem $df$ is an immersion on $B$, thus having full rank $R$; hence $I=R$. This shows that $X^c$ is non-empty (and dense indeed since the same argument works on every open subset of $M$). $\square$
Thus, there exists a non-empty open $U\subset M$ on which $df$ has full rank. Since $f\vert_{U} : U \to N$ is injective, by Global Rank Theorem $df$ is an immersion on $U$, so $\text{dim }U\le \text{dim }N$. From here we can only conclude $\text{dim }M\le\text{dim }N$.

Proof 2: Netto's Theorem
By Netto's Theorem, if there exists a continuous bijection from $M$ to $N$, then they have the same dimensions.
(However, I cannot find the proof of this theorem. Moreover, the proof does not seem to be an easy one, as both Cantor and Netto gave faulty proofs. Also, this theorem seems to be an overkill.)

Is it clear that in Proof 1 U is not empty?

@VictorZurkowski I have added a proof showing that $X^c$ is indeed open and dense, thus one can choose a non-empty $U$.

By Sard's Theorem, we have plenty of regular values $y\in N$ of $f$. Choose one. Since $f$ is bijective, there is a unique $x\in M$ with $f(x)=y$ and $df_x\colon T_xM\to T_yN$ is surjective. Thus, $\dim M\ge \dim N$. Moreover, by the local submersion theorem (Guillemin & Pollack, p. 20), $f$ is locally a projection. The fact that $f$ is a bijection therefore forces $\dim M=\dim N$.
COMMENT: Since you assumed only that $f$ is $C^1$ rather than smooth, I have to be careful in applying Sard, as if $\dim M>\dim N$, further differentiability is necessary. However, you've already argued that $\dim M\le\dim N$, so I'm saved.

Originally I had two proofs, one using Sard's Theorem and the other using Global Rank Theorem, and later realized they are both faulty. Surprisingly they work well when combined!

I think you can do this without using Sard's theorem (though it might morally be very close to the "easy" part of Sard's theorem, it uses the Baire category theorem rather than the notion of measure zero to show that if $\dim(M)<\dim(N)$ its image would have to be "small").
Let $m=\dim(M)$, $n=\dim(N)$, and for any non-negative integer $k$ let
$$
M_k = \{x \in M: \text{rank}(df_x)=k\}.
$$
Thus necessarily $M_k=\emptyset$ for all $k \geq \min\{m,n\}$. Let $k_0 = \max\{k: M_k \neq \emptyset\}$ and let $M_{\geq k} = \bigsqcup_{l\geq k} M_l$. Then $M_{\geq k}$ is open in $M$ for all $k$ and thus in particular $M_0 := M_{k_0}$ is an open subset of $M$. Now the restriction $f_0$ of $f$ to $M_0$ has constant rank, and hence locally has the form
$$
\pi_r\colon \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^n: (x_1,\ldots,x_m) \mapsto (x_1,\ldots,x_{k_0},0,\ldots,0) \in \mathbb R^n
$$
Thus since $f_0$ is injective, we must have $k_0 =m=\min\{m,n\}$.
Now the above argument only used the injectivity of $f$, hence we may apply it with $M$ replaced by any arbitrary open subset $U\subseteq M$, and hence we see that $M_0$ is dense in $M$. But now if $V\subseteq N$ is open in $N$ then $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $M$ and hence
$$
f(M_0)\cap V = f(M_0\cap f^{-1}(V)) \neq \emptyset
$$
and hence $f(M_0)$ is dense in $N$. We claim this implies that $n \leq m$.
Suppose for the sake of a contradiction that $n>m$. For each $p\in M_0$, pick charts $(U_p,\phi_p)$ centred at $p$ and $(V_p,\psi_p)$ centred at $q=f(p)$ such that $f$ is given by $\pi_m$ in the corresponding coordinates, and let $B_p$ be the preimage under $\phi_p$ of an open ball centred at the origin in $\phi_p(U_p)$ whose closure is contained in $\phi_p(U_p)$. Then as $m<n$, $f(\bar{B}_p)$ is a closed, compact nowhere dense subset of $N$. Now $\{ B_p: p \in M_0\}$ is an open cover of $M_0$, which, as $M_0$ is second countable, contains a countable subcover, thus there is a sequence $(p_n)$ in $M_0$ with $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} B_n = M_0$ where $B_n = B_{p_n}$ (for all $n \in \mathbb N$). But then $f(\bar{B}_n)$ is a closed nowhere-dense subset of $N$, and thus by the Baire category theorem, $\bigcup_{n \geq 1} f(\bar{B}_n)$ is nowhere dense. But
$$
\bigcup_{n \geq 1} f(\bar{B}_n) = f(\bigcup_{n \geq 0} \bar{B}_n) = f(M_0)
$$
hence we have a contradiction, and $n\leq m$ as required.
To be clear, the first part of this argument is that of "proof 1". What is added is the observation that $M_0$ is dense, and that this property is inherited by $f(M_0)$.
